# htaccess redirect -redirect all pages from root to /blog/ folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Redirect all pages in ROOT (ex: ROOT/page-name/) directory only to /blog/page-name/ directory
2. DO NOT redirect sub directories with NAMES - "/cities/", "/states/", "/categories/" under ROOT directory

I just want to redirect all existing Wordpress pages from ROOT to /blog/ and NOT redirect pages that I will be adding later with /cities/, /states/ and /categories/ names in them.

Please help! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules you may already have there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog|cities|states|categories)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Looks right and this is also what I came up with but I keep getting a redirect loop, any ideas why?

Comment: @Walter Nope, it [works just like you asked for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8qlr2.png). You sure there isn't something else that is also redirecting?

Comment: I'm running Wordpress, do you know of any redirects it may be doing that I should disable?

Comment: @Walter and Wordpress knows not to redirect pages that start with `/blog/`?

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/ROOT/)([/]?.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ROOT /blog/%2 [L,R=301]
```